# Can I use EF and Linq, if I am getting connectionstring at runtime?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

We have a database where all connection strings are saved in a table. I need to use these connection strings to obtain data in their respective database. I can do it running queries but I want to use Linq and EF. How can I do it?

Thanks a lot.

Let me rephrase again, I am having access to database which will have a table containing multiple connection strings. I want to map database at runtime and then use it to retrieve the data. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to map database at runtime. It will work only if your application knows mapping for every database and has all necessary classes prepared = you will have to create it in design time.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav, so in EF4 it is not possible but in future version it might or technically it is not possible? Just for curiosity. Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm not sure how to achieve this technically with statically strongly typed language. ORM maps between tables and classes. If you add table you must somehow add class and you must have code using this class. Without using full dynamic approach or emitting code at runtime it doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 2):

`ObjectContext` exposes [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739017.aspx), which takes a connection string argument, so you can do:

```
ObjectContext yourContext = new ObjectContext(yourConnectionString);
```

Comment: So can I map database, create temprary objects and then use then to run a query?